# Unity GLSL shader - getting screen coordinates

Tags: unity-game-engine, glsl, shader

I am porting a shader toy shader to Unity GLSL. It's working except I have trouble getting the screen space coordinates I need. What's the equivalent of this:

```
vec2 coord = gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
```

It seems gl_FragCoord is not available and how do I get the screen size?

Note that I'm using GLSL as the shader language in Unity not CG or HLSL.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#define iResolution _ScreenParams
#define gl_FragCoord ((_iParam.scrPos.xy/_iParam.scrPos.w) * _ScreenParams.xy)

struct v2f {    
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;    
    float4 scrPos : TEXCOORD0;   
};              

v2f vert(appdata_base v) {  
    v2f o;
    o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos (v.vertex);
    o.scrPos = ComputeScreenPos(o.pos);
    return o;
} 

fixed4 frag(v2f _iParam) : COLOR0 { 
    return main(gl_FragCoord);
}
```

the main function is your 'mainImage' function on ShaderToy.

Comment: If you are using HLSL/CG, you can use the code above, sorry not see the question clearly.

Comment: Your define was superuseful to me in replicating the exact same behaviour from Shadertoy to Unity, your answer is more generic and deserves more upvotes!

Answer (score 1):

I think I got the answer:

```
 GLSLPROGRAM // here begins the part in Unity's GLSL

 #include "UnityCG.glslinc"

 vec4 iResolution = _ScreenParams;
```

Then in main() in fragment shader:

```
vec2 coord = gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
```

I must have made a mistake that made me believe I did not have access to gl_FragCoord